# Is there a LWC method to get fieldTypes by passing a list of fields?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Need some help in getting the field Types without calling Apex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) to fetch the data types. You should use `data.fields.fieldName.dataType`.

Sample code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
    oppInfo({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.dataTypes = Object.values(data.fields).map((fld) => {
                let { apiName, dataType } = fld;
                return { apiName, dataType };
            });
            console.log('this.dataTypes => ', JSON.stringify(this.dataTypes));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "apiName": "AccountId",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Amount",
    "dataType": "Currency"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "CampaignId",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "CloneSourceId",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "CloseDate",
    "dataType": "Date"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "ContactId",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Convert_RecordType__c",
    "dataType": "Picklist"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "CreatedById",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "CreatedDate",
    "dataType": "DateTime"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "CurrentGenerators__c",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "DeliveryInstallationStatus__c",
    "dataType": "Picklist"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Description",
    "dataType": "TextArea"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "ExpectedRevenue",
    "dataType": "Currency"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Fiscal",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "FiscalQuarter",
    "dataType": "Int"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "FiscalYear",
    "dataType": "Int"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "ForecastCategory",
    "dataType": "Picklist"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "ForecastCategoryName",
    "dataType": "Picklist"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "HasOpenActivity",
    "dataType": "Boolean"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "HasOpportunityLineItem",
    "dataType": "Boolean"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "HasOverdueTask",
    "dataType": "Boolean"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Id",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "IsClosed",
    "dataType": "Boolean"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "IsDeleted",
    "dataType": "Boolean"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "IsPrivate",
    "dataType": "Boolean"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "IsWon",
    "dataType": "Boolean"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "LastActivityDate",
    "dataType": "Date"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "LastModifiedById",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "LastModifiedDate",
    "dataType": "DateTime"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "LastReferencedDate",
    "dataType": "DateTime"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "LastViewedDate",
    "dataType": "DateTime"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "LeadSource",
    "dataType": "Picklist"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "MainCompetitors__c",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Name",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "NextStep",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "OrderNumber__c",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "OwnerId",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Pricebook2Id",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Probability",
    "dataType": "Percent"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "RecordTypeId",
    "dataType": "Reference"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Snapshot_Opp__c",
    "dataType": "Url"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "StageName",
    "dataType": "Picklist"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "SystemModstamp",
    "dataType": "DateTime"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Test_Field__c",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "TotalOpportunityQuantity",
    "dataType": "Double"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "TrackingNumber__c",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "apiName": "Type",
    "dataType": "Picklist"
  }
]
```